# MVC 3, Asp.net 4 - Error in application - the resource can not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I just created an empty application, added a view, a controller and ran it.

I am getting the following error:

"The resource cannot be found."
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

My code:
TestController.cs

```
namespace WOSubmittal.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

View located under Views/Test

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

I put a breakpoint to the  Index() routine and it doesn't even get hit. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe is it because your controller is named TestlController instead of TestController (typo error ?)

Comment: Do you have a HomeControler ? Have you registered your default route in the global.asax ? Are you running it from Visual Studio or deployed to IIS (either local or remote) ?

Comment: no HomeController (it's an empty app). Running it from VS 2010 on a local machine.

Comment: What do you have in your global.asax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this in   `public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)`

```
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

for this:

```
new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

in your Global.asax.cs

Comment: nope no luck. May have to just create a non empty application like I always did before, as this is taking way too long to resolve.

Comment: Try my solution and..right click the project and choose "Properties", click the "Web" tab and choose "Specific Page", leaving the text box blank..

Answer (score 1):

Change `TestlController`  to `TestController`.

When looking for a view for your controller, MVC will use the name of your controller, without the word Controller, when attempting to resolve it.

From the code you've given, MVC would look in Views/Testl, not Views/Test.

Comment: my typo. It's TestController. Sorry - just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in the Web.config file:

```
<httpRuntime enable="false" targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

to

```
<httpRuntime enable="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
```